# Webscraping: How to check if attribute exists and if it doesnt continue without ending program

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a website to get desired contact information like cellphone, email, adrress, etc,etc...

Some pages will have all information...while some may only have cellphone and email but not address... and any combination of having/not having these fields inbetween...

Ive been playing around with some code but cant quite figure it out

how do i check to see if the information i want exists on a page(because it wont always be consistent) and if it isnt simply ignore and scrape all "available" information and then continue on without breaking the program

code i am trying:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_class_name('zsg-list_definition'):
                trial = soup.findAll('dl', {'class': 'zsg-list_definition'})
                if len(trial[0].dd.text) > 0:
                    address = trial[0].dd.text
                else:
                    address = 'None'

            if driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dont-break-out') == True:
                websiteURL = soup.find('dd', {'class': 'dont-break-out'})
                website = websiteURL.a.text
            else:
                    website = 'None'

            csv_writer.writerow([address, website])
```

best regards

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Your question is too broad for this forum so it will probably be hard to find an answer (if it is not closed). Please read our community guidelines in the help section before making questions.

Personally I don't see any problem regarding web scrapers in your question. Try doing a few tutorials on web scraping like [this easy one](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-web-scrape-with-python-in-4-minutes-bc49186a8460), that will help you clear your mind

Comment: the question is everything to do with web scraping @Lucas Wieloch

Comment: @mcfoyt Can you edit your question and put there short html with examples of your input data. To have something concrete to work with...

Answer (score 0):

could just use `try except`:

```
...

try:
    address = trial[0].dd.text
except:
    address = 'None'

try:
    websiteURL = soup.find('dd', {'class': 'dont-break-out'})
    website = websiteURL.a.text
except:
    website = 'None'

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have quite a bit of experience with this.

You're going to want to use some [try and except blocks](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) in your code to catch the errors when the scraper fails to find something. I also added an 'else' block into your address check for if len(trial[0].dd.text) returns 0 so that address will still be set to 'None'.

```
try: 
     trial = soup.findAll('dl', {'class': 'zsg-list_definition'})
     if len(trial[0].dd.text) > 0:
         address = trial[0].dd.text
     else:
         address = 'None'
except:
     address = 'None'

try:
     websiteURL = soup.find('dd', {'class': 'dont-break-out'})
     website = websiteURL.a.text
except:
     website = 'None'

csv_writer.writerow([address, website])
```

Comment: im getting the following error "illegal target for variable annotation" when i try running @Daniel Glynn

Comment: @mcfoyt, I fixed some syntax errors, go ahead and try it now.

Comment: don't use bare excepts